# How to write a function that includes pipes using functions from the srvyr package?

Tags: r, pipe

I have a survey that I am trying to get to be grouped by years and the calculate totals for certain variables. I need to do this about 20 times with different variables so I am writing a function but I can't seem to get to work properly even though it works fine outside the function.

this works fine:

```
 mepsdsgn %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(tot_pri = survey_total(TOTPRV)) %>% select(YEAR, tot_pri)
```

when I try a function:

```
total_calc <- function(x) {mepsdsgn %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(total = survey_total(x)) %>% select(YEAR, total)}

total_calc(TOTPRV)
```

I get this error: Error in stop_for_factor(x) : object 'TOTPRV' not found

Comment: Is TOTPRV the name of something (a string, like the name of a variable) or is it an actual object?

Comment: its a column name in the dataframe mepsdsgn

Comment: Then you should be referencing it as a string when calling the function .... that's problem one, fix that. Then you can refer to it as `mepsdsgn[[x]]` in your function

Comment: total_calc <- function(x) {mepsdsgn %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(tot = survey_total(mepsdsgn[[x]])) %>% select(YEAR, tot)}

total_calc(mepsdsgn[[TOTPRV]])
``` 
and 

```total_calc <- function(x) {mepsdsgn %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(tot = survey_total(x)) %>% select(YEAR, tot)}

total_calc(mepsdsgn[[TOTPRV]])```

both still get the error Error in stop_for_factor(x) : object 'TOTPRV' not found

Comment: https://medium.com/optima-blog/writing-your-own-dplyr-functions-a1568720db0d I think this would solve the problem but the package is sryvr and not dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

total_fun <- function(x) {
  col = x
  mepsdsgn %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(total = survey_total(!!sym(col), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% select(YEAR, total)
}

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things I'd suggest doing, see below

```
# first try to make a working minimal example people can run in a new R session
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.frame(y=1:10, x=rep(letters[1:2], each=5))

# simple group and mean using the column names explicitly
dt %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(mean(y))

# a bit of googling showed me you need to use group_by_at(vars("x")) to replicate
# using a string input
# in this function, add all arguments, so the data you use - dt & the column name - column.x
foo <- function(dt, column.x){
  dt %>% group_by_at(vars(column.x)) %>% summarise(mean(y))
}

# when running a function, you need to supply the name of the column as a string, e.g. "x" not x
foo(dt, column.x="x")
```

I don't use `dplyr`, so there may be a better way